# Как заменить слово в docx файле не теряя форматирования

Tags: python, python-3.x, docx, python-docx

Возникла проблема мне нужно заменить слово в док файле, но с сохранением всех шрифтов.

я использовал подобный код, но он удаляет форматирование

```
import docx
 
document = docx.Document("example.docx")
 
for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
    paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace("old", "new")
 
document.save("example.docx")
```

Comment: [Вот примеры решения](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34779724/python-docx-replace-string-in-paragraph-while-keeping-style), может пригодится

Comment: спасибо это, то что нужно.